# routes in play 2 framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am novice to play 2.0.3 framrwork. Is there any way that there would be only one entry in route file for all controllers and actions as follows:

/{controller}/{action}       /controller/action

- controller would be any controller
- action would be any action

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For type safety (routes in Play 2 are compiled, so you know they are valid at compile time), a catch all route is not supported.

The only way you can do it, is to send all your routes to a single controller, and then redirect your code from within that controller, but I don't think that will be suitable for you.

Answer (score 1):

That approach doesn't fit the `type safety` - main idea of Play 2.0, so it's just suggested to create proper routes for each action also declaring the params with proper types to make sure that every route (also reverse route) always hits the required target action.

Of course you can also write own action for `sub-routing` where you can catch whole path ([Dynamic parts spanning several /](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaRouting) ) and manually redirect to some action, however it still requires creating lot of common routes + lot of custom type validation in it etc, etc, so using original router is just faster and cleaner approach.